# Remove server info from Apache mod_autoindex and error page footers

Tags: apache-2.2

How to remove server info at the bottom of the directory listing?

It looks like this: `Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server`

Comment: As edited, the ServerSignature also appears on any apache error page, not just mod_autoindex pages.

Comment: thank you for the thoughtful edits and clarification @EEAA

Answer (score 8):

Add `ServerSignature Off` line inside either the .htaccess, the virtual host file, or the main config file.

More info can be found in [the official apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serversignature).

Answer (score 3):

Add `ServerSignature Off` to your main Apache config file.

Also search for `ServerSignature On` in your whole apache config folder:

```
cd /etc/apache2
grep -R 'ServerSignature On' * | grep -v '#'
```

and change all findings with `ServerSignature Off`

Also search in your web folder for such setting in all `.htaccess` files:

```
find /var/www/ -name ".htaccess" -print | xargs grep "ServerSignature On"|grep -v '#'
```

If those findings are too many, you can use `sed` to replace in the resulting output  `ServerSignature On` with `ServerSignature Off`